# Wordpress - $wpdb->get_results not getting any result

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a small function in a custom page to get the content from a table and to display it to the user. It was working correctly before but since I changed the DNS it isn't working anymore.

Before, my code looked like this :

```
global $wpdb;
$table = "0_luxcom_token";
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM $table");
$resultat = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

PHP was returning an error because `prepare()` didn't have an argument but it was still working.
Now, PHP is returning me a fatal error so it doesn't work anymore. I changed my code to this :

```
global $wpdb;
$table = "0_luxcom_token";
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM %s", $table);
$resultat = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

I don't get any error from `prepare()` but now, `get_results->($query, ARRAY_A);` doesn't return anything.

I tried `var_dump($resultat)` and it returned me

> array(0){   }

Then I tried `var_dump($query)` and it returned me

> string(54) "SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM '0_luxcom_token'"

I noticed when I put my table in the argument it's now between simple quote, so I wonder if it's because of this it's not working anymore but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it is because of this. You cannot bind table names in `prepare`.

Comment: So what can I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no variables to prepare for query, use simple [`query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/) method:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = "0_luxcom_token";
$query = $wpdb->query("SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM $table");
$resultat = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

Or just [`get_results`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/):

```
global $wpdb;
$table = "0_luxcom_token";
$resultat = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT token_name, token_dateexp FROM $table", ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out this method, I didn't think about it.
However, I still haven't got any result with `get_results();` even if `query()` works

Comment: See the update. Also I provided links to wp-manual. Please open it in case of something goes wrong.

Comment: Just the `get_results()` alone works for my case, thanks !